# Will the headers be plain once the Ethereum StackExchange launches?

Tags: discussion

Who designs the headers I see on StackExchange pages? Are they community created or does StackExchange themselves make them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, it is done by the designers at StackExchange, after consulting the members of the community.

However, I think it would be a very long time before we graduate in order to discuss on this topic! So, it might change at that time.

Comment: I like this answer a lot! Should be interesting to see what they come up with. (After looking at the subreddit, the official site, and the look and feel of the youtube videos.)